# Find the most recent row of a group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I know there is no "last" row so I hope I'm clear that isn't what I'm really looking for. I want to select the rows in a table if the value of one particular field is the last alphabetically. I'll try my best to draw it out below. I'm a bit of a novice so please bear with me...

TABLE
[Order Number], [Delivery Date], [Order Qty], [Shipped Qty], [Bill To], [Ship To], [Invoice Number]

There are many times when we will reissue invoices and that invoice number will increment by a letter. This will also update additional field values as well. Below is a typical set with multiples invoices...

```
'987654', '2014-05-01 00:00:00', '100',  '90',  'BillToXYZ', 'ShipToXYZ',               '987654A' - NEW RECORD - 
'987654', '2014-05-01 00:00:00', '-100', '-90', 'BillToXYZ', 'ShipToXYZ',               '987654B' - NEW RECORD - 
'987654', '2014-05-01 00:00:00', '100',  '100', 'BillToXYZ', 'ShipToNEWSHIPTOLOCATION', '987654C' - NEW RECORD - 
'987654', '2014-05-01 00:00:00', '10',   '10',  'BillToXYZ', '2ndNEWSHIPTOLOCATION',    '987654D' - NEW RECORD -
```

What I need is to query all the above fields and only bring back those where the [Invoice Number] is the last(alphabetically) (in this case 987654D) but also have it SUM the values of the [Order Qty] and [Shipped Qty] for all of the records regardless of [Invoice Number].

If I can provide any additional information please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the original invoice number is without letter or always 'A'?

Comment: Original invoice number is always A. The invoice number will always be the order number with a letter after it. If that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It possible to use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to get the last row in a group setting the `ORDER BY` descending and then using a filter to get the row with the value 1. 
The `SUM` and `MAX` with windowing help to get the other aggregate values.

```
WITH D AS (
  SELECT [Order Number]
       , [Delivery Date]
       , SUM([Order Qty]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order Number]) [Total Order Qty]
       , [Total Shipped Qty] 
       = SUM([Shipped Qty]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order Number]) 
       , [Bill To]
       , [Ship To]
       , [Last Invoice Number] 
       = MAX([Invoice Number]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order Number])
       , ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Order Number] 
                                 ORDER BY [Invoice Number] DESC)
  FROM   Table1
)
SELECT [Order Number]
     , [Delivery Date]
     , [Total Order Qty]
     , [Total Shipped Qty]
     , [Bill To]
     , [Ship To]
     , [Last Invoice Number]
FROM   D
WHERE  ID = 1
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/667b9/2)</kbd>

Comment: This solution works for me! Thank you very much. I've been trying to get this all week. Now I just need to understand what's happening in the query. This is my first question. What do I have to do to vote or give credit or however it works?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're going after?

**EDIT 2:** Got clarification from OP.  Have edited my solution to bring up aggregation for complete order but only the line item information of the latest invoice.  Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08bb0/6

```
SELECT t1.[Order Number],
       t2.[Max Invoice Number],
       t1.[Ship To],
       t2.[Sum Order Qty],
       t2.[Sum Shipped Qty]
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT    [Order Number],
                MAX([Invoice Number] ) AS [Max Invoice Number],
                SUM([Order Qty]) AS [Sum Order Qty],
                SUM([Shipped Qty]) AS [Sum Shipped Qty]   
      FROM     Table1
      GROUP BY [Order Number]) t2
      ON t1.[Invoice Number] = t2.[Max Invoice Number]
ORDER BY t1.[Order Number];
```

You can add more columns from the D invoice by placing them in the SELECT list from t1, as I did with [Ship To].

**EDIT 1:** Added grouping so whole table is considered.  To be fair, Martin K. posted this answer first.

Comment: Let me give this a try.

Comment: I left out the where clause because I would need this for all records. I also added in the additional fields such as the [Ship To] and I am still getting multiple rows per invoice. I would need just the values of the fields for the D (in this example) or "last" alphabetically invoice but a SUM of all invoices.

Comment: I see.  SUM of all invoices with the same order number, correct?

Comment: Exactly. SUM of all invoices with the same order number but also the other fields such as [Ship To] from the "last" (in this case the D invoice) row. These non-numeric fields also change on the invoices that's why I want the "last" one.

Comment: Got it.  Give me a sec to think.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you can use a GROUP BY and aggregates as suggested by other answers, but put that in a subquery so that you can link your 'main' table to it and get the detail values for the latest invoice.  Does the following code do what you're looking for?

```
CREATE TABLE #Table 
  (
    OrderNumber int, 
    DeliveryDate datetime, 
    OrderQty int, 
    ShippedQty int , 
    BillTo varchar(10), 
    ShipTo varchar(100), 
    InvoiceNumber varchar(20)
  )

INSERT INTO #Table 
  (
    OrderNumber, 
    DeliveryDate, 
    OrderQty, 
    ShippedQty, 
    BillTo, 
    ShipTo, 
    InvoiceNumber
  )

SELECT '987654', '2014-05-01 00:00:00', '100',  '90',  'BillToXYZ', 'ShipToXYZ',               '987654A' UNION
SELECT '987654', '2014-05-01 00:00:00', '-100', '-90', 'BillToXYZ', 'ShipToXYZ',               '987654B' UNION
SELECT '987654', '2014-05-01 00:00:00', '100',  '100', 'BillToXYZ', 'ShipToNEWSHIPTOLOCATION', '987654C' UNION
SELECT '987654', '2014-05-01 00:00:00', '10',   '10',  'BillToXYZ', '2ndNEWSHIPTOLOCATION',    '987654D'


SELECT t.*, s.TotalOrderQty, s.TotalShippedQty
FROM 
    #Table t
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            OrderNumber, 
            MAX(InvoiceNumber) LastInvoice, 
            SUM(OrderQty) TotalOrderQty, 
            SUM(ShippedQty) TotalShippedQty
        FROM #Table
        GROUP BY OrderNumber
      ) s ON 
        t.OrderNumber = s.OrderNumber AND
        t.InvoiceNumber = s.LastInvoice

DROP TABLE #Table
```

Comment: Let me give it a try.

Comment: This gives me the 3 rows as the result. It omits the A invoice row.